# Unable to open Google chrome using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying open a google chrome using selenium webdriver but I'm getting the below error :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 18885
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 110 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:41'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.244.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at demo.main(demo.java:9)
```

I have tried everything but no use.

Below is my program :

```
public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Internal job application\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Need assistance on what action  needs to taken

Comment: Do you have chrome installed on you machine ?

Comment: What is the location of chrome browser installation

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your `chrome` browser is not installed in the default installation directory or selenium not able to find executable chrome browser file.

To solve this problem, you need to tell the program where your chrome browser executable is present and for that you can use `ChromeOptions` class like below :

```
public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Internal job application\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/binary"); // Provide absolute executable chrome browser path with name and extension here
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Tried the same found error again.

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 22906
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: no chrome binary at /path/to/chrome/binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT

Comment: Search for `chrome.exe` in your system and replace that file path with ` /path/to/chrome/binary` in this line `options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/binary");`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Chrome browser in destination by default.
2. In this line:

   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "destination to file"

`destination to file` is not destination to installed Chrome browser, but destination to downloaded [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) chrome driver.